# Custom bootstrap column sizing affecting the field's placemement as well, when nothing changed other than field width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here is a piece of bootstrap code layout and actual page -

```
<div <div class="container-fluid">
                    <section class="row well" id="accrual-search-screen1">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                    <label for="plan year">{{ 'as.PlanYear' | translate }}</label> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="plan year">{{ 'as.MaximumCompensation' | translate }}</label> 
                                    <input type="text" formControlName="rebate" name="rebate" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="company">{{ 'as.MaximumMatch' | translate }}</label> 
                                    <input type="text" formControlName="rebate" name="rebate" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="company">{{ 'as.CatchUpContribAge' | translate }}</label> 
                                    <input type="text" formControlName="rebate" name="rebate" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="company">{{ 'as.CatchUpAmount' | translate }}</label> 
                                    <input type="text" formControlName="rebate" name="rebate" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="company">{{ 'as.ExcessAnnualAdditionalLimit' | translate }}</label> 
                                    <input type="text" formControlName="rebate" name="rebate" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZTIc.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/mytgX.png  -  The original look of fields in the page.

What I need - to reduce the width of textboxes, from 18(col-md-2) to 12. For this, I wrote this custom css-

```
.col-md-1half { width: 10.416666%; } ~ approx. 1.25*width of 1 column.
and replace  **col-md-2** with **col-md-1half**. (Only 1 change in html)
```

That **solves** my purpose exactly - getting textbox of length of 12 characters.

But strangely, the layout becomes like this (image II)- Same image.

What is that I could be possibly missing here? Any other detail that should be included here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The new image  - where the issue lies, is this -    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZTIc.png

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the div with the col-md-2 in another div and reduce that size of that one.

```
<div class="smaller-width">
   <div class="col-md-2">
       //filler 
   </div>
</div
```

CSS:

```
.smaller-width {
  width: 12px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Reducing the size wasn't really the issue here, the issue was - disturbed alignment of the textboxes. Could you check the images?

Comment: My bad, I think your problem may lie in the col-md-offset. Check out this link - > http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets